# Show Google Analytics Data to Users

Tags: google-analytics, dashboard

I am building a website and every user will upload images. The users' images will have unique IDs. The users will have their own dashboard with analytics.

I want to provide every user with analytics data (unique visitors, page views, bounce rate, etc.) for their own information. I am thinking of using google analytics for this instead of building something on my own.

Can this be done through google analytics legally? Are there any restrictions on showing such analytics information directly to the user?

Comment: If you solved it please let others know how you did it i am also searching for a similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

The legal restriction with the Google TOS is that Google must not have any way to connect collected data to an existing person ( "data which can be reasonably linked to such information by Google", [TOS §7](http://www.google.com/analytics/terms/us.html)). You are allowed to store anonymous IDs that can be matched in your own backend to persons as long as they cannot be resolved to individual users by Google.